# How can i export my Grails services in jar, and use that jar in some other java application?

Tags: spring, grails, grails-orm

I am exporting the class file from grails in java.but it doesn't working for me.is this is possible to do or not?? if yes then how??

---

Its a simple groovy service file.
Bookservice.groovy

```
package com.compnyname.testingJar

class BookService {

    List<Book> getallBooks(String name){
            List<Book> bookList= Book.findAllByName(name);
            return bookList;

        }
}
```

Book.groovy(Domain class)

```
package com.compnyname.testingJar

class Book {
    String name;
    String description;
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

java file in which i am using this service is as follows

```
import com.compnyname.testingJar.*;
public List<Groups> listGroup() {
        List<Groups> groups = null;
        try {
            BookService bService = new BookService();
            logger.debug("class of bookservice is" + bService.getClass());
            List<Book> books = bService.getallBooks("xyz");
            logger.debug("List of books is" + books);
            groups = sessionFactoryHibernate.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Groups").list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return groups;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you [create a Grails plugin](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#creatingAndInstallingPlugins) you can [export it as a jar](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#binaryPlugins) which you can then add to the classpath of your Spring/Struts project.

Comment: Hi David thanks for replying.I tried it.but its working fine for me in grails application but not in spring application.is there any additional configuration required for it.Have you ever try it with spring or struts??

Comment: I haven't no - when you say it's not working, is it compiling? can you see the classes in the Spring/struts project? or is it just that the Grails service isn't working as expected in the Spring/Struts project?

Comment: can you provide a code sample for the Grails service you're trying to call from Spring/Struts from the jar?

Comment: The problem here is that you are directly instantiating `BookService` where as in Grails it would be built with its dependencies injected in by Spring. If the Grails service wasn't depending on being built in this way the it would work but from the example you've shown I think you'll have to go with a different approach. Why can't you just query the db in the Spring controller/service?

Comment: This project may help you make use of GORM in Spring: https://github.com/domix/gorm-standalone

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the services in a plugin project and import the plugins from other projects where you would like to use the services

Comment: I want to  use that plugin in any spring or struts project??how i will configure that plugin in my spring project.??